# What is the point of using multiple exclamation marks in sed?

Tags: sed, posix

[POSIX sed documentation](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/sed.html#tag_20_116_13_03) said:

> A function can be preceded by one or more '!' characters, in which
>   case the function shall be applied if the addresses do not select the
>   pattern space. Zero or more <blank> characters shall be accepted
>   before the first '!' character. It is unspecified whether <blank>
>   characters can follow a '!' character, and conforming applications
>   shall not follow a '!' character with <blank> characters.

So, with any POSIX sed, we can:

```
sed -e '/pattern/!d' file
```

It's the same as writing:

```
sed -e '/pattern/!!d' file
```

And `!!!d` and `n` of exclamation marks are still be fine (Tested with three `sed` version from [heirloom toolchest](http://heirloom.sourceforge.net/tools.html)). I don't see any benefit between multiple instead of one exclamation.

Why did the spec allow that syntax and how is it useful in real world application?

---

It seems that GNU sed is not compliant in this case, it will complain if we use multiple exclamations:

```
$ sed -e '/pattern/!!d' file
sed: -e expression #1, char 11: multiple `!'s
```

Comment: FWIW: On OpenBSD `!` acts as a toggle, `/pattern/!!` is the same as `/pattern/`, and `/pattern/!!!` is the same as `/pattern/!`.  On FreeBSD multiple `!` are the same as a single one.

Comment: The point of a lot of stuff in the spec is that `sed` scripts can be *generated*. Given a POSIX `sed`, it should be a realtively simple matter to to script  the writing of a `sed` script. And so if you had some trigger for some case which should mark an address `!` not worthy of whatever your action was, you might even trigger that multiple times for the same one and still come out with the same results.

Comment: @cuonglm No, only FreeBSD's is.  The GNU, OpenBSD, and NetBSD `sed`s aren't.

Comment: @lcd047: yeah, of course. Sorry for my bad English. I mean it isn't compliant, is it. It's good to know that. But the main point in my question is *how* that syntax can be useful in real world, with POSIX sed?

Comment: Well @mikeserv has mentioned an use case.  I'm not aware of any other. _shrug_

Comment: FWIW: a fix for this has been committed in OpenBSD-current.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`sed`'s API is primitive - and this is by design. At least, it has *remained* primitive by design - whether it was designed primitively at inception I cannot say. In most cases the writing of a `sed` script which, when run, will output *another `sed` script* is a simple matter indeed. `sed` is very often applied in this way by macro preprocessors such as `m4` and/or `make`.

*(What follows is a highly hypothetical use case: it is a problem engineered to suit a solution. If it feels like a stretch to you, then that is probably because it is, but that doesn't necessarily make it any less valid.)*

---

Consider the following input file:

```sh
cat <<"" >./infile
camel
cat dog camel
dog cat
switch
upper
lower
```

If we wanted to write a `sed` script which would append the word *-case* to the tail of each *appropriate* word in the above input file only if it could be found on a line in *appropriate context*, and we desired to do so as efficiently as possible *(as should be our goal, for example, during a compile operation)* then we should prefer to avoid applying `/`regexp`/`s as much as possible.

One thing we might do is pre-edit the file on our system right now, and never call `sed` at all during compilation. But if any of those words in the file should or should not be included based on local settings and/or compile-time options, then doing so would likely not be a desirable alternative.

Another thing we might do is process the file *now* against regexps. We can produce - and include in our compilation - a `sed` script which can apply edits according to line number - which is typically a far more efficient route in the long-run.

For example:

```sh
n=$(printf '\\\n\t')
grep -En 'camel|upper|lower' <infile |
sed "   1i${n%?}#!/usr/heirloom/bin/posix2001/sed -nf
        s/[^:]*/:&$n&!n;&!b&$n&/;s/://2;\$a${n%?}q"'
        s/ *cat/!/g;s/ *dog/!/g
        s| *\([cul][^ ]*\).*|s/.*/\1-case/p|'
```

...which writes output in the form of a `sed` script and which looks like...

```sh
#!/usr/heirloom/bin/posix2001/sed -nf
:1
    1!n;1!b1
    1s/.*/camel-case/p
:2
    2!n;2!b2
    2!!s/.*/camel-case/p
:5
    5!n;5!b5
    5s/.*/upper-case/p
:6
    6!n;6!b6
    6s/.*/lower-case/p
q
```

When that output is saved to an executable text file on my machine named `./bang.sed` and run like `./bang.sed ./infile`, the output is:

```
camel-case
upper-case
lower-case
```

---

Now you might ask me... *Why would I want to do that? Why would I not just anchor `grep`'s matches? Who uses camel-case anyway?* And to each question I could only reply, *I have no idea...* because I don't. Before reading this question I had never personally noticed the *multi-!* parsing requirement in the spec - I think it's a pretty neat catch.

The *multi-!* thing *did* immediately make sense to me, though - much of the `sed` specification is geared toward simply parsed and simply *generated* `sed` scripts. You'll probably find the required `\n`ewline delimiters for `[wr:bt{]` make a lot more sense in that context, and if you keep that idea in mind you might make better sense of some other aspects of the spec - *(such as `:` accepting no addresses, and `q` refusing to accept any more than 1)*.

In the example above I write out a certain form of `sed` script which can only *ever* be read once. If you look hard at it you might notice that as `sed` reads the edit-file it progresses from one command-block to the next - it never branches away from or completes its edit-script until it is completely through with its edit-file.

I consider that *multi-!* addresses might be more useful in that context than in some others, but, in honesty, I can't think of a single case in which I might have put it to very good use - and I `sed` a lot. I also think it noteworthy that GNU/BSD `sed`s both fail to handle it as specified - this is probably not an aspect of the spec which is in much demand, and so if an implementation overlooks it I doubt very seriously their *bugs@* box will suffer terribly as a result.

That said, failure to handle this as specified *is* a bug for any implementation which pretends to compliance, and so I think shooting an email to the relevant dev boxes is called-for here, and I intend to do so if you don't.

Comment: It's now fixed in OpenBSD-current.

Comment: Multiple `!` is going to be removed in [next spec](http://austingroupbugs.net/view.php?id=944), what's going on here!

Comment: @cuonglm - too little too late, i guess. maybe i was nearer to the mark than i thought.

Comment: @cuonglm - well, ok, but what does that... *Accepted as Marked* even mean?

Comment: @mikeserv: the answer explained my wonder and gave me another view with sed API. It make sense to me!

Comment: @cuonglm - im pleased it pleased you. But what does *Accepted As Marked* mean in the POSIX bug tracker? The `-E` ERE for `sed` has been *Accepted As Marked* for 2 or 3 years.

Comment: @mikeserv: As the [doc](http://austingroupbugs.net/file_download.php?file_id=2&type=doc) said, it mean the ticket was under reviewed.